# Differences between the functions addtime() and convert() on MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, time

I've been messing around with MySQL , trying to work on a calendar, I got this doubt while investigating about the datetime type.

```
addtime ('2012-01-01 01:00:00','00:00:00');
convert ('2012-01-01 01:00:00', datetime);
```

The sentences above, on my understanding, are supposed to convert a string to the data type datetime, is my statement true?, or Is there a difference between them?

Comment: Well, `addtime` is for adding a time to a date. A conversion when the time is missing is just a side-effect.

Comment: So, the correct way to do it, is with 'convert()', but if I use 'addtime()', there'll be no problem. I'm supposing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer the MySQL documentation for the functions: [ADDTIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime) and [CONVERT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert).

**ADDTIME**

> ADDTIME() adds expr2 to expr1 and returns the result. expr1 is a time
>   or datetime expression, and expr2 is a time expression.
>
> mysql> SELECT ADDTIME('2007-12-31 23:59:59.999999', '1 1:1:1.000002');
>           -> '2008-01-02 01:01:01.000001' mysql> SELECT ADDTIME('01:00:00.999999', '02:00:00.999998');
>           -> '03:00:01.999997'

**CONVERT**

> CONVERT(expr,type), CONVERT(expr USING transcoding_name)
>
> The CONVERT() and CAST() functions take an expression of any type and
>   produce a result value of a specified type.
>
> The type for the result can be one of the following values:
>
> BINARY[(N)]
>
> CHAR[(N)]
>
> DATE
>
> DATETIME
>
> DECIMAL[(M[,D])]
>
> SIGNED [INTEGER]
>
> TIME
>
> UNSIGNED [INTEGER]

The way you have used `addtime` MySQL should have given error. Since `ADDTIME` takes to 2 arguments and you are passing only one.

Hope it helps...

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed, I missed an argument, I'll edit it right away, so, if I add an argument, like 'addtime ('2012-01-01 01:00:00', '00:00:00')', it will still convert it, but it's not the right way to do it. Now it's clear for me, and I guess , I found what I was needing, I will end up using 'adddate()' for my purposes. Thanks for the info.